# Correct HTTP status code to use for query beyond known data

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm defining an API and have come across a question I've not had to deal with before. I was wondering what the consensus on here would be for the best status code to use for a response where the result is not known (yet).

To explain, the GET endpoint in question doesn't return a resource, it just a tool to return specific information about known dates.

The backend calendar data it's using to do this is manually loaded in chunks periodically. So if a user makes a query for a date that is beyond (or prior to) the date range that has been loaded, how should the API respond?

Initially i was thinking a 4xx error, but the syntax and query is technically valid. Trying the exact same query at another time (when the data for that date has been loaded) would result in a successful response.

Looking at 5xx errors, non seem to be an ideal match. 503 Service Unavailable looks closest to me, but seems to focus on temporary errors. This situation might last for months potentially. A compounding problem is that the API itself doesn't know when more data will be loaded so we can't easily use the Retry-After header either.

What would you do?
Thanks!

Comment: By `manually loaded in chunks periodically` I assume that a background task in your frontend is constantly streaming in new date entries from the backend and a request handled by your frontend just returns date entries within the scope of the time range requested? In such a case I feel it's natural to only return what is currently available and within the requested time range at the time the request takes place. If the time range is completly outside of any available date entries I'd return an empty list/set to indicate that no data was found for the given time range. Hence `200 OK` is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `202 Accepted` means that the service successfully accepted the request and there are, as of yet, no problems with it (i.e. no immediate data validation problems), but it can’t create the resource until it does further processing. This response does not promise that the resource will be created, though. So, it’s perfect for pending requests, since a pending request could be rejected while it’s being processed.

It is also importat to append `Location` header with endpoit serving actual status of the async operation such that client able to monitor it on a peridoic basis.

Comment: If you already poll for the current status of a resource there is no need to add an additional `Location` header to the response. This header should only be used to inform a client that a further resource got created as a result of the request received and its content can be looked up via the given URI. As `GET` requests are safe though, processing such a request SHOULD (MUST?) NOT create further resources. Therefore such a header does not make any sense within a response to a `GET` request

Comment: I think perhaps a 204 No Content would be the choice here. The request is valid, but there is nothing to return.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use a 4xx or 5xx HTTP status code for this.**

They should only be used if there is an error in the request or the response, and there isn't.

4xx errors means the request failed (which it didn't) and 5xx means server error.

Definitely use a 2xx reply, either 200 OK or 202 Accepted

Answer (score 0):

> To explain, the GET endpoint in question doesn't return a resource, it just a tool to return specific information about known dates.

That's a resource, in the [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) sense.

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

In particular, the fact that something is a resource does not in any way depend on the implementation used to provide the representation of the resource.

> if a user makes a query for a date that is beyond (or prior to) the date range that has been loaded, how should the API respond?

Usually by returning a message-body that explains to the client what the problem is, and including in the meta data a response code that indicates the nature of the response to generic components.

In particular, you want to be paying attention to how *caches* are supposed to interact with your response, given that they will only be looking at the metadata, not the payload.

In most cases like this one, you want to report the error *and instruct caches to store the response for later use*.

So you'll want to use status code [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

`404` is, in effect, a hint that the spelling of the target-uri is wrong, or that the client shouldn't have asked for this particular resource.  In either case, it is a problem with the request, and should be handled that way.

> Trying the exact same query at another time (when the data for that date has been loaded) would result in a successful response.

Note that the HTTP standard explicitly calls out the fact that `404` may be used in *temporary* conditions:

> A 404 status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent

Comment: Whether to use 200 OK with a representation format that indicates empty state or returning 404 Not Found is more or less an opinionated choice as responses to both are cacheable by default and future request may lead to different results. In favor of the typical context flow used on Web pages that depict a scrollable resultset (think of entries you might page through) I'm more in favor of returning page that states that no entries are available in the DB or the like compared to a 404 error page that might give the impression that the actual link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But thinking about it now, i agree with the other posters that a 2XX response is a slightly better match in this particular case.